# Remote MySQL server returning: MySQL server has gone away / Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: linux, mysql, php, apache2

I have 2 servers (both running Ubuntu 12.04)

APP server

- running `apache2`, `PHP7.2` and a `CakePHP 2.0` APP

DATABASE server

- running `mysql 5.7`

When I'am trying to insert into the database a big blob (starting > 40MB) the mysql server returns the following errors to the APP:

`Error while sending QUERY packet`

`General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`

Also in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` - i found the following error:

`[Note] Aborted connection 123456 to db: 'database_name' user: 'database_username' host: 'remote_ip_address' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

---

in `PHP.ini`, i've maxed: `max_execution_time`, `memory_limit`
in MySQL configs, i've maxed `wait_timeout`, `net_read_timeout`, `net_write_timeout`, `max_allowed_packet`

I've checked `free -m` there is enough ram. i am not using persistent connection, i've tested multiple times and its look like failing between 19-22 seconds everytime. i don't have other idle mysql procceses.

Can you guys suggest how i can debug this futher? I have no ideas left. Maybe a firewall issue? But how i can debug that. Thanks!

Comment: What query were you running?  How long did it run before timing out?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`

Comment: I've write it up. after 19-22 seconds. its an INSERT query of a BLOB (55MB file). all variables from `'%timeout%'` are increased to their max.

Answer (score 0):

Not even `LONGBLOB` can handle more than 4GB; certainly not 55GB.  Do not plan on putting that big a cell into a MySQL table.

You could break it into chunks, but that is a pain.

Instead, make a file, then have the URL provide a way to get to the file -- just a JPGs are handled on web pages.

Comment: I don't know where i write 55GB. Its happening starting with 55MB (wich is low and not a big problem to store). I cannot change the whole APP back to local storage. i need a fix for this problem. (its already in production like this for years)